# I loop over 4 objects and render their images while applying a class based on the truthness of a property but sometimes the DOM doesn't rerender

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I loop over 4 objects and render their images while applying a class based on the truthness of a property BUT sometimes the DOM doesn't update/rerender with the right classes even though the object's property value has changed from true to false or vice-versa and I have no idea why is this happening.

Let me explain what exactly is happening. I render 4 images with class `card-image` and the active image gets an extra class `active`. I've binded a on-click function to each image so that when the user clicks the image, that image becomes the active one and the previous active image becomes inactive. This works to a certain degree, however, if I start clicking the images in a certain order, the DOM stops getting rendered with the correct classes on the correct image. For example:

Image 1 is active by default. If I click image 3, image 3 gets the active class. Then if I click image 1 again, image 3 losses the active tag and image 1 receives the active class

However in the following scenario, something goes wrong:

Image 1 is active by default. If I click image 3, image 3 gets the active class. Then if I click image 2 or image 4, image 3 doesn't lose its active class and image 2 or 4 don't get the active class EVEN THOUGH the console shows that image 3 property active has become false and image 2/4 property active has become true.

I've included a gif that showcases what happens: https://gyazo.com/81e1c89fffc6c84d8ffead751a223b01.

```
<div v-for='card in associatedCards'>
    <div class="card-image" :class='{ active: card.active }' @click='makeCardActive(card)'>
        <img :src='"../assets/cards/" + card.cardCode + ".webp"'>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    import cards from '../assets/json/set1-en_us.json'

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                cardCode: this.$route.params.cardCode,
                cards: cards,
                card: null,
                associatedCards: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            makeCardActive(card){
                this.activeCard.active = false
                card.active = true
                console.log(this.associatedCards)
            }
        },
        computed: {
            activeCard(){
                return this.associatedCards.find((card) => {
                    return card.active == true
                })
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.card = this.cards.find((card) => {
                return card.cardCode == this.cardCode
            })

            let associatedCards = this.cards.filter((card) => {
                return this.card.associatedCardRefs.includes(card.cardCode)
            })

            let combinedArray = [{...this.card}, ...associatedCards]

            combinedArray.map((card) => {
                card.active = false
            })

            combinedArray[0].active = true

            this.associatedCards = combinedArray
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some delay in the code, to be safe just make all cards to false then set the active card to true

```
            makeCardActive(card){
                this.associatedCards = 
                this.associatedCards.map(aC => {
                    aC.active = false; 
                    return aC;
                 });
                this.activeCard.active = false
                card.active = true
                console.log(this.associatedCards)
            }
        },
```

Comment: Hmm the map function gives me this error "Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'active' of undefined"" which is strange as aC is not undefined.